# Hadoop datanode blocks storing information

Tags: hadoop

I want to find out how many blocks are stored in particular `Datanode` in the  `Hadoop` cluster. And which file those blocks belong to.. I have only a `2-node` cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have only 2 node clsuter all the blocks will be stored there. In general I dont think so that you can find easily which blocks are present on datanode. What is the use case by the way for this

Comment: i am getting under replicated block message in namenode webui so i want to know which all blocks are under replicated.

Comment: All the blocks. You need to set dfs.replication property to 2, Since you have 2 nodes

Comment: I have used same property but still i am getting 50 under replicated blocks. i will share u which all blocks are under replicated by using fsck command.

Comment: /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/mapred/mapred/staging/training/.staging/job_201303062236_0009/job.jar:  Under replicated BP-2100437999-127.0.0.1-1355878275444:blk_689498454953722996_1240. Target Replicas is 10 but found 3 replica(s).
.
/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/mapred/mapred/staging/training/.staging/job_201303062236_0020/job.jar:  Under replicated BP-2100437999-127.0.0.1-1355878275444:blk_2990514071682559257_1436. Target Replicas is 10 but found 3 replica(s).

Comment: i have changed that job.jar default property to 2 still same msg under replicated.

Comment: Just curious....are you sure that your second datanode is running fine. To see this, are you getting the hdfs directory( name which you configured) getting made there.

Comment: Ya datanode is running properly and getting hdfs directory.

Comment: Ok got it...its your job jar file. I remember reading somewhere it is replicated with high replication factor. There is some property to set this. I dont remember it now. Google for it

Comment: set the following property in mapred-site.xml ..<property>
<name>mapred.submit.replication</name>
<value>2</value>
<description>The replication level for submitted job files.  This
  should be around the square root of the number of nodes.
</description>
</property>

Answer (score 0):

Go to the HDFS webUI by pointing your web browser to `NameNode_Machine:50070`. Come down to the `Cluster Summary` and click on `Live Datanodes`. It'll show you all the DataNodes available currently in a table whose last column will show you the number of blocks.

And to find the relation between a files and its blocks you could open that file in webUI and and scroll down. It'll show you all the blocks of that file along with the location of each block.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hadoop fsck` command with argument `-locations` to know the locations for each block.

```
Usage: hadoop fsck [GENERIC_OPTIONS] <path> [-move | -delete | -openforwrite] [-files [-blocks [-locations | -racks]]]
```

[Here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html#fsck) is the reference page, search for fsck for more information.